# Can I have two columns inside a Bootstrap Panel?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, panel

Just getting started with Bootstrap.

Is there a way of having two columns in side a panel?

Thanks

Comment: I guess using a table would be a less expensive option.

Comment: Have you tried something??

Answer (score 47):

Sure.. just like you'd create any Bootstrap columns:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="panel-heading">Title</div>
     <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">col1</div><div class="col-md-6">col2</div>
        </div> 
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">col1</div><div class="col-md-6">col2</div>
        </div> 
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">col1</div><div class="col-md-6">col2</div>
        </div> 
     </div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/114526

Answer (score 1):

You can also have a [panel with a table](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels-tables):

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="panel-heading">Title</div>
     <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
        </tr>
     </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Which bypasses the efficiency of Bootstrap... Various Bootstrap components employ styles having "display: table" which have almost the same functionality as HTML tables, but are more flexible.

Comment: "Panel - With tables" is a standard feature of Bootstrap.  Why do you think it "bypasses the efficiency of Bootstrap"?

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but I think @Gabe is trying to say that we should never, ever, ever in any situation whatsoever use a table, which is wrong.  We shouldn't use tables for layout, of course, but I have many sections in my web app that handle raw data that should be displayed in table form.  This is the Bootstrap way of adding tables to a panel.

Comment: I second that opinion. Tables for layout = **very bad**, but if your layout is tabular it's perfectly okay to use them.

Comment: Subject the content to the semantics test. Is your data semantically tabular (as in, is the data you're displaying contextually tabular)? Or did you just want a grid (usually a low-dimensional grid, like a few rows) for visual alignment purposes? Latter, use bootstrap grids.